# .toggle on div from <a> not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla3.0

I am wanting to show a hidden div when I click on a link. I am using Joomla for my CMS, and i've double checked that it is loading jQuery. This will be  containing my login, here's what I have currently.

HTML

```
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-container").toggle()
    });

    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        $("#" + divId).toggle();
    }
</script>
</head>
 <body>
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('login-container');">Login</a>
    <div id="login-container">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#login-container {
float: right;
z-index: 50;
padding: .2em 1.5em;
border-radius: 5px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 3em;
left: 30%;
width: 16em;
height: 9em;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wait, just try the following. No reason to have redundancy in code.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('login-container');">` – why this archaic type of event handling, when you’re using jQuery already?

Comment: What do you want it to toggle?

Comment: Just remove `javascript:`  http://jsfiddle.net/dzmy5tun/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla loads jquery in noconflict mode.

You have to change your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#login-container").toggle()
    });

    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        jQuery("#" + divId).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Reference: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly, also thanks for the reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, just try the following. No reason to have redundancy in code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {             
         $(".toggler").click(function(){
           e.PreventDefault();
           $("#login_container").toggle();    
         });
    });
</script>
</head>
 <body>
<a href="" class='toggler'>Login</a>
    <div id="login_container">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
```

If you want to use it as a function, use selectors and traversing to always find the dom elemtn, and name them all the same selector. Also, good idea to always use underscores in name id's, but can use "-" in class names.

Answer (score -1):

You could try `onclick=toggleDiv(divId);return;` but there is bound to be a simpler jQuery.